# SoftArtisans Error: Unable to parse formula: Unable to find function 'IFERROR' in function table

Tags: excel, officewriter

Well, this is perfectly work on all version of excel. 
Except SoftArtisans library which I use. I do not want to buy new version. I just want update to this bug only.

Advance information was send by mail to support also.

Here some intro

> Error:
>   Unable to parse formula: Unable to find function 'IFERROR' in function table.; Unable to find function 'IFERROR' in function table.
>   Row: 6

StackTrace = "   at SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter.Formula.Ptg.ᜇ.ᜀ(String A_0, ᜋ A_1)\r\n   at SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter.Formula.Ptg.\u1716.ᜀ(String A_0, IList`1 A_1, String A_2, ᜋ A_3)\r\n   at SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.Parser.Txt2Ptg.ᜁ.ᜀ(ᜃ A_0)\r\n ...

```
// Type: SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter.Cell
// Assembly: SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter, Version=7.6.0.2814, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f593502af6ee46ae
// MVID: 86DFA65A-7B7D-4BDD-9BD7-A23DDE47DC04
// Assembly location: \Bin\SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter.dll

SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter.Cell.Formula



this.sheet.Cells[TheRow, 11].Formula = "=IFERROR( CHOOSE(L7,\"A1\",\"R2\",\"S3\",\"I4 R\",\"P R\",\"Snse ve\",\"Suspensr\",\"Deleted\",\"InMark\",\"Peng\",\"veyed\",\"veyed\"),\" \")";                
this.sheet.Cells[TheRow, 12].Value = item["id"];
```

[image][image]

Reported: 1/18/2018
Thanks

Great library!!!